# One question about proof of martingale representation theorem

Tags: stochastic-processes

Does any one know which book I can find the proof of martingale representation theorem in detail?  I.E. Any $F_B$ adapted local martingale M is continuous and can be written as a integration of Brownian.

There is a proof on my notes.  It says there exists a sequence of stopping times {$T_n$} such that $M^{T_n}$ is a bounded martingale.   But we don't know M is continuous, I don't know how to construct a well-defined sequence of stopping times to make $M^{T_n}$ be a bounded martingale.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are many references for example Philip E. Protter's book [Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Stochastic_Integration_and_Differential.html?id=mJkFuqwr5xgC).

On the net George Lowther's Blog [Almost sure](http://almostsure.wordpress.com) where [this post](http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/05/25/the-martingale-representation-theorem) should do the trick.

Best regards